# Custom Django include function

Tags: python, django

All my JavaScript is run through Django's compiler, allowing me to inject HTML strings Underscore templates in the following manner:

```
var htmlStr = '{% filter convert_js_template %}{% include "my_file.html" %}{% endfilter %}'
```

This code runs the output from the included HTML file through the `convert_js_template` filter, which simply removes line breaks and escapes single quotation marks so that the final JS string is valid. To make it more readable, however, I'd like to be able to simply write something like the following:

```
var htmlStr = '{% convert_js_template "my_file.html" %}'
```

How can I create a `convert_js_template` function that will accomplish this? My sense is that it needs to start out by doing the following:

1. Grab the contents of the desired file
2. Parse the contents for any Django template tags

I tried the following:

```
@register.filter('convert_js_template')
def convert_js_template(path):
    value = include(path)
    return value.replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace("'", "\\'")
```

I initially received the error `NameError: global name 'include' is not defined`, so then I added `from django.conf.urls import include` to the file and am now receiving a different error: `ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.`

And this is where I'm stuck :)

Comment: I personally think this method is an overkill - The JS is going through an additional compilation step which is not necessary - Ideally, you would send the data in context, or populate a JS object on init and fetch the values from the object. Also, you could just use the `{% include %}` tag which is not the same as the url include.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I would use the `{% include %}` tag? I am currently using that (see the first code snippet).

Comment: Actually, i did not mean the rendering of HTML from JS - I would revist the architecture -  (without looking at the code), i believe all the JS logic could be delegated to Django, and simplified. Another problem with too much JS means more requests back to the server behind the scenes - which is something you would like to avoid.

Comment: You can have a look at the source: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/template/library.py

Comment: In your `convert_js_template` filter, why don't you simply read the content of the `path`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution doesn't involve a custom "include" function exactly. Instead, it manually loads and renders the desired template file:

```
from django.template import Library, loader, Context

...

register = Library()

...

@register.filter('js_template')
def js_template(template_path):
    tpl = loader.get_template(template_path)
    return tpl.render(Context({})).replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace("'", "\\'")
js_template.is_safe = True
```

Note that `template_path` should be relative to the directory you have set for Django to look in for templates.

Usage:

```js
var htmlString = '{{  "path/to/my_template.html" | js_template }}';
```